# IOS event for onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, html, ios, mobile-safari

I am looking for a replacement to the onbeforeunload event handler to use on IOS as onbeforeunload event isn't supported on Safari mobile. ([Link to Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload))

Comment: There probably isn't any.

Comment: "*onbeforeunload event isn't supported on Safari mobile*" really? MDN says "no" but links to a bug report that's 10 years old. caniuse says that `beforeunload` is supported in "effectivly all browsers"